# How to Customise VSCode id attributes?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I've recently moved from Atom to VSCode, while I managed to customise most of the editor according to my likings, I am still missing a few features that Atom had that I enjoyed.

One of those things is that the "id" attribute in Atom used to be a specific colour, something similar to #99FFFF. I've looked through themes but I couldn't manage to find one that makes the id attribute colour different then the rest of them.

Another feature that I enjoyed was the fact that when a new HTML element was created, eg. a div, it came with the most used, basic attributes by default. I got the hang of using the emmet snippets but it still doesn't work the same, probably because I don't know exactly how to use it properly yet. If there is a cheat sheet for this it would be greatly appreciated, or at least a few examples. Let's say I want to create an input element with a type, name, id and placeholder attribute, how would I go about to do that with emmet snippets?

Here is my settings.json

```
    "editor.fontFamily": "'JetBrains Mono', Consolas, monospace",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.letterSpacing": 0.4,
    "editor.smoothScrolling": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",

    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.background": "#232323",
        "sideBar.background": "#272727",
        "sideBar.foreground": "#C9C9C9",
        "editor.foreground": "#C9C9C9",
        "statusBar.background": "#272727",
        "activityBar.background": "#232323",
        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#232323",

    },
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
```

Comment: if you want the id attribute colored different you have to use extension **Highlight** because all attributes have the same TextMate Scope

Comment: create snippets with the properties you want, or create custom emmet macros, see VSC Emmet doc page

Comment: Do you want the word `id` colored or its value?  You can color either one or both if you want.  See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color of the word `id` or its attribute value using the `tokenColorCustomizations` object in your `settings.com`:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
       {
        "scope":    [
          "meta.attribute.id.html entity.other.attribute-name"  // the word id
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ff0000",
          // "fontStyle": "bold"
        }
       },
      {
        "scope": [
          "meta.attribute.id.html string.quoted.double.html"  // the id's vaue
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ff0000",
          // "fontStyle": "bold"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

See [Editor Syntax Highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-syntax-highlighting).